# Domain Object in Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

We've been having a discussion at work about whether to use Domain Objects in our views (asp.net mvc 2) or should every view that requires data be sent a ViewModel?

I was wondering if anyone had any pros/cons on this subject that they could shed some light on?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like to segregate my Domain Objects from my Views. As far as I'm concerned, my Domain Objects are solely for the purpose of representing the Domain of the application, now how the application is displayed.

The presentation layer should not contain any domain logic. Everything they display should be pre-determined by their Controller. The ideal way to ensure this is always adhered to is to ensure the view only receives these flattened ViewModels.

I did ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387292/asp-net-mvc-is-this-entity-layer-a-step-too-far) myself. Here's a quote from the answer I accepted:

> I think that there are merits to
>   having a different design in the
>   domain than in the presentation layer.
>   So conceptually you are actually
>   looking at two different models, one
>   for the domain layer and one for the
>   presentation layer. **Each of the models
>   is optimized for their purpose**.

If I have the domain objects for `Customer` > `Sales` > `Dispatch Address`, then I don't want to have to deal with the object traversal in my view. I create a flattened view model that contains all of the properties. There's almost no extra work in mapping to and from this flattened view/presentation model if you use the excellent open source project [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Also, why would you want to pass an entire domain object back to a view if you can create an *optimised* representation of that model?

Comment: +1, but what about simple domain objects, like a Category, that just has Id and Label ? For some applications with lots of these, it can become quite annoying to create MyEntity { Id, Label } and MyDto { Id, Label }, where the only thing differing is the name.

Comment: @mathieu - Obviously you can use your discretion when it comes to examples like this :). Domain Objects such as your example would not contain any domain logic and therefor would certainly be acceptable.

Comment: ok that's what I thought. if you have some time, could you have a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539108/asp-net-mvc-model-inheritance ?
I'm not really new with asp.net mvc technical stuff, but for the "philosophical" and design, I could use some pointers !

Comment: There might be "almost no extra work" in mapping to/from the flattened models, but there sure is extra work in creating and maintaining 2 (or even 3, in the case of separate entity models) sets of models and maintaining them.  It's easy to see why the question of "can I somehow get away from model separation and mapping?" keeps coming up.  I really wish there was a way, frankly.  In practice, for simple applications, creating a bunch of view models and mapping to/from domain models is a lot of unnecessary redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

If you use NHibernate or similar - your domain objects will most likely be proxies, serializing these dun work. You should always use a ViewModel and map your domain objects to DTOs within your viewmodel. Don't take shortcuts here. Setting the convention will alleviate the pain you'll suffer later on.

It's a standard pattern for a reason.

w://

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In some case it will be fine to use instances of model classes. In other cases a separate ViewModel is the better choice. In my experience it is perfectly acceptable to have different models in your domain and in your views. Or to use the domain model in the view. Do what works best for you. Do a spike for each option, see what works and then decide. You can even choose a different option for each view (and/or partial).

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely going to be simple little apps where it's fine to use the same models across all layers.  Generally little forms over data apps.  But for a proper domain, my thoughts on the subject are to keep the domain models and view models separate because you don't want them to ever impact each other when changed.

If the domain logic needs a small change to process some new business logic on the back end, you don't want to risk that altering your view.  Conversely, if marketing or someone wants to make changes to a view, you don't want those changes leaking back into your domain (having to populate fields and maintain data for no other purpose than some view somewhere is going to use it).

Answer (score 1):

I have a good comparision currently because I'm working on two projects using different approaches. I'm far from stating that "this is bad and this is good" because this is written in some patterns. I know patterns, I like patterns, but I never blindly follow them just to be right. I always use what do I need currently to achieve current goals.

In first app, using domain objects in view, development is very quick. Few changes in few places and you have additional properties, form inputs etc. You don't bother about the layers, just extends/change the code and pass to another problem.

In the second app, where there are always object for use here, there and somewhere else, there's a dozens of classes looking the same, doing the same, and a ton of conversion code between various version of the same objects. More bad is that some developers do some logic on "this version" of class, and other logic is done on "that version". Development is very painful and requires a lot of testing afterwards. Changing a simple thing requires a lot of attention and a lot of code need to be changed. I really don't like this app for that, because I've never yet seen a business benefits from this approach, at least during last year (and we are in the production stage from the year). This app is three-four times more expensive to develop and maintain than the first one.

So, my funny answer on the question is: it depends. If you work in 10-20 people team, you like to come into the work, drink few coffies, talk with friend, do few simple things and go home, a lot of intermediate objects and conversion code will be good for you. If your goal is to be fast and cheap, if you want to focus on business layer, new features, quick changes following, and more if you touch software business and want to cash your project (we do all this stuff to be finally sold, right?), the second approach would be probably better.